# Broken syntax in Postfix header_checks

Tags: regex, postfix-mta, email-headers

I`m setting up Postfix to edit the headers dependent on the reciever. This is done through header_checks(http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html)

The logic is as follows:
If the e-mail is sent to "erik@sorgaard.net" then we copy the From field and an paste it to the Reply-To field, the From field is also set to "erik@sorgaard.net".

I have no experience with regexp but through some searching I was able to come up with the following:

```
if /^To: (erik@sorgaard.net)\s.*$/
/^From: (.+@.+)\s.*$/ PREPEND Reply-To:$1
/^From: (.+@.+)\s.*$/ REPLACE From: erik@sorgaard.net
endif
```

This does not work. I'm not sure what's wrong with the syntax, but any help would be very appreciated.

Regards Erik

Comment: did you want the regex to match `id's`?

Comment: No, I´m not aware of any ids here, just pure e-mail addresses represented as strings. This syntax: (.+@.+) is merely to match the actual e-mail address and not any tailing string that contains name.

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) says `if /pattern/flags   endif`  If  the  input  string  matches `/pattern/`, then match that input string against the patterns between if and endif. While your pattern is `To` header, how can you match `From` headers inside `if`?

Comment: Well the `if` statement is only really dependent on the `To` field. Aslong as that matches the script should edit the `From` and `Reply-To` fields. I know my code might be very borked, but Im totally lost here and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the header_checks are applied only one time for each email line, so the seconf "From" line (line 3) is skipped.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the accepted answer might mislead.

If you fight with if-endif in header_checks you should keep in mind the following:

```
If  the  input  string  matches /pattern/, then match that input
string against the patterns between if and endif.  The if..endif
can nest
```

from http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html

Pay attention to "then match **that** input string". This means you can't operate any header inside the if/endif block but the one you use in if-statement.